# Tikz problem : starting picture on top left exactly

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, alignment

I am wrinting a python script that makes a latex file for [avery 3668](https://www.avery.nl/template-3668) labels. I do this with the tikz package (each label is a node). My problem is that the nodes are not centered in the labels of the sheet (there is no margin on the avery sheet). Here is what I mean :

[image]

The problem is actually that my tikzpicture doesn't begin at the top left of my sheet exactly. How would you fix it ?

Here's the latex code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=0cm,vmargin=0cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
\node [text width=0.5cm, align=left, anchor=north, color=white] at (0, 0) {+};\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (5.25, -8.839285714285714) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (10.5, -8.839285714285714) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (15.75, -8.839285714285714) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (0.0, -10.960714285714285) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (5.25, -10.960714285714285) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (10.5, -10.960714285714285) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (15.75, -10.960714285714285) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (0.0, -13.082142857142856) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (5.25, -13.082142857142856) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (10.5, -13.082142857142856) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (15.75, -13.082142857142856) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (0.0, -15.203571428571427) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (5.25, -15.203571428571427) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (10.5, -15.203571428571427) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (15.75, -15.203571428571427) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\node [draw,align=center, inner sep=6pt, double, font=\itshape,text width=4.25cm, anchor=north] at (0.0, -17.325) {Rhubarbe\\ \vspace{-0.15cm}\pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\vspace{0.075cm}\\10 février 2024};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but nesting `tikzpicture`s is generally not recommended, I believe. Instead you could place all the nodes relative to `current page.north west` directly, e.g. with `\path (current page.north west) ++(x,y) node ...`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `pgfornament` loads the package `tikz` so `\usepackage{tikz}` was removed.

Loops with `\foreach` are used to place all nodes. In this way, the code for the `\node` only needs to be typed once.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x in {1,...,4}{
  \foreach\y in {1,...,5}{
    \node[
      draw,
      align=center,
      inner sep=6pt,
      double,
      font=\em,
      text width=4.25cm
    ]
    at ({\paperwidth*\x/4},{2.1cm*\y})
    {Rhubarbe\\[-0.15cm]
    \pgfornament[width=1cm]{80}\\[0.075cm]
    10 février 2024};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer ! I didn't thought to use the \centering command.